# How to different invocations of same state machine in parallel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, state, state-machine, aws-step-functions

I have a state machine that gets triggered based on a file on S3 bucket using an event. If 2 files come one after the other, two executions of state machine starts running. I do not want that. Instead of using a queue, can I do something within the state machine to ensure that when an instance of state machine is running, the second invocation goes on wait until the fist one completes?

A solution within state machine confit

Answer (score 0):

Then the state machine would have to internally store the invocations in a queue, while it waits for the current invocation to finish. As far as I'm aware,  AWS Step Functions does not provide that feature for you.

Amazon has [published a blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/controlling-concurrency-in-distributed-systems-using-aws-step-functions/) about using locking to stop the concurrent state machine invocations from actually doing anything, until they can acquire a lock. This effectively allows  you to have only one state machine invocation running at a time, while Step Functions basically "stores" the invocation until such time as it can run.

I don't think this will provide any sort of ordering however. I think if multiple invocations are waiting for a lock, as soon as the lock is released the next one to run will be totally random. A queue seems purpose-built to solve the actual problem you are trying to solve, so I highly suggest thinking about using a queue.